# How to connect JPA entity classes? (one-to-many/many-to-one)

Tags: java, jpa, entities

If have these two entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME") //Attributes in the entitiy
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME") //Attributes in the entitiy
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "HOUSE_NUMBER")
    private int houseNumber;
```

How do I now connect these two entities and define that `Customer` has many `Addresses`?

Comment: Please do some Googling. I think that SO has also lots of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find tons of examples of this over Internet. I highly suggest to take a look at [ObjectDB website](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed).

For this specific scenario, you can define them as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME") //Attributes in the entity
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

and have a reference to your customer in Address class as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME") //Attributes in the entitiy
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "HOUSE_NUMBER")
    private int houseNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on your request to have an example for many to many relation, here is the way you can implement it for your Customer and Address entities:

First you should have an intermediate table having two foreign keys, one referring to customer table and the other referring to address. Suppose you name this intermediate table `customer_address`, then it's data would be something like this:

```
select * from customer_address;

customer_id | address_id
------------------------
    12      |     15
    12      |     14
    12      |     13
    2       |     15
    2       |     13
    19      |     11
```

Now you should update your annotations and tell JPA to use this table to infer the many to many relationship among your entities.

Customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME") //Attributes in the entity
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_address", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME") //Attributes in the entitiy
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "HOUSE_NUMBER")
    private int houseNumber;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_address", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Customer> customer;
}
```

In this code annotations are used to provide following information to JPA:

- `@ManyToMany`: indicates the type of the relationship
- `@JoinTable`: used to specify the table holding the actual relationship data and has following attributes:

  - `joinColumns`: Defines the column in the intermediate table that refers to the entity class that contains the `@ManyToMany` annotation. In `Customer` class, it defines the column that is a foreign key to `customer` table and in `Address` class, it defines the column that is a foreign key to `address` table.
  - `inverseJoinColumns`: It's the exact opposite of the `joinColumn` property. Defines the column in the intermediate table that refers to the entity class that is on the other side of the `@ManyToMany` annotation. In `Customer` class, it defines the column that is a foreign key to `address` table and in `Address` class, it defines the column that is a foreign key to `customer` table.

I know that my description is not as readable/understandable as it should be, but you know it's not easy to describe the `@JoinTable` annotation. Reading the sample code itself and matching column/property names to find the meaning of each one would be an easier approach. Also you can check it in [ObjectWeb](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinTable) website (includes a sample too).

Comment: @user10 I updated my answer with another scenario for many to many relation

Answer (score -1):

You should be having a xml file to define which table this entity is referring to, you can then add their field and relationship there.

example:

```
<entity class="class" access="FIELD">
<table name="class_table" />

 <attributes>
    <id name="classId">
        <column name="class_id" />
    </id>

    <basic name="className">
        <column name="case_name" />
    </basic>

<!-- Foreign key many-to-one -->
    <many-to-one name="classType" fetch="LAZY">
        <join-column name="class_type_id" referenced-column-name="class_type_id" />
    </many-to-one>

<!-- Foreign key one-to-many -->
    <one-to-many name="class_list"  mapped-by="class" fetch="LAZY" />
 </attributes>
 </entity>
```

Comment: Can't I directly do it in the code where i create the entities?

Comment: @user10 sure you can, simple add annotation ManyToOne or OneToMany, then you will be alright, i thought you are asking for another approach.

Comment: Okay because I'm just learning it and I'm looking for the easiest way to do it...

Comment: @user10 please be aware that there is no the easiest way to do it, but one of the way, it is more than a configuration, it involves code consistency, operation and flow.